# Combining SUM and WHERE - not getting the results I expect

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT shop.price,shop.item,shop.full_item_name,shop.qty,shop.shop_id,
SUM( averages_20128.combined_prices + averages_20127.combined_prices ) AS combined,
SUM( averages_20128.total_sales + averages_20127.total_sales ) AS total
FROM `shop`
JOIN `averages_20128`
ON averages_20128.full_item_name=shop.full_item_name
JOIN `averages_20127`
ON averages_20128.full_item_name=averages_20127.full_item_name
JOIN `theShops`
ON theShops.id=shop.shop_id
WHERE shop.price<combined/total
AND theShops.open='1'
AND shop.id!=''
AND `total`>10
ORDER BY combined/total DESC
LIMIT 100
```

Error: Unknown column 'combined' in 'where clause'

Overview: I have considered creating a column that stores the current average and ordering on that, however I didn't do that when I first started and now have mountains of data. I would rather not go through it all and re-calculate this. So I'm hoping MySQL can do the math for me.

This does work when I leave out the WHERE/ORDER clauses, leading me to believe that there's something wrong with my syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have said, it doesn't work because `combined` isn't available in the `where`  clause.

The order of execution is as follows in SQL:

```
FROM clause
WHERE clause
GROUP BY clause
HAVING clause
SELECT clause
ORDER BY clause
```

so names you define in `select` are not available in `where` - also, aggregates like `sum` are only available after `Group By` has been executed.

What I am *guessing* you want is actually something like this

```
SELECT shop.price,shop.item,shop.full_item_name,shop.qty,shop.shop_id, 
combined, total
FROM `shop`
JOIN (
    SELECT averages_20128.full_item_name, 
    SUM(averages_20128.combined_prices + averages_20127.combined_prices) AS combined,
        SUM( averages_20128.total_sales + averages_20127.total_sales ) AS total
    FROM `averages_20127` JOIN averages_20128
        ON averages_20128.full_item_name=averages_20127.full_item_name
    GROUP BY averages_20128.full_item_name
) AS averages
ON averages.full_item_name=shop.full_item_name
JOIN `theShops`
ON theShops.id=shop.shop_id
WHERE shop.price<combined/total
AND theShops.open='1'
AND shop.id!=''
AND `total`>10
ORDER BY combined/total DESC
LIMIT 100
```

The values of `total` and `combined` are computed in the sub-select and then compared against the current shop prices.

Again, its not entirely clear what you want to do, so this might not be what you need.

Comment: You sir, are a gentleman and a scholar and have thought me much today! Thank you!

Comment: I will clarify that I changed the ORDER BY to: ORDER BY shop.price-(combined/total) ASC ... So basically it is trying to item shops that are selling merchandise for below average, and then order them by which have the highest savings.

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
WHERE shop.price < combined/total
```

To:

```
WHERE shop.price <
  SUM(averages_20128.combined_prices + averages_20127.combined_prices)/total
```

Or move it to a `HAVING` clause:

```
HAVING shop.price < combined/total
```

`WHERE` is applied before `SUM()`, so the aggregate columns are not available to it yet. `HAVING` occurs nearly last.

Answer (score 0):

The `combined/total` uses columns from the result set, not from the original data.

In order to reference them like this you'll either need to reproduce the calculation that created them, or use a sub query to do that calculation, and then filter and order in the outer query.

Answer (score 0):

To use `SUM` you need to have a `GROUP BY` somewhere.

Comment: Also true, although I think that would be the next error message that he got rather than the present one.

Comment: If I run this, MySQL returns no errors: SELECT shop.price,shop.item,shop.full_item_name,shop.qty,shop.shop_id,
SUM( averages_20128.combined_prices + averages_20127.combined_prices ) AS combined,
SUM( averages_20128.total_sales + averages_20127.total_sales ) AS total
FROM `shop`
JOIN `averages_20128`
ON averages_20128.full_item_name=shop.full_item_name
JOIN `averages_20127`
ON averages_20128.full_item_name=averages_20127.full_item_name
JOIN `theShops`
ON theShops.id=shop.shop_id